# Как запросы приходят на nginx?

Tags: nginx, http, маршрутизация

Новичок в веб ремесле, поэтому возник вопрос, возможно весьма глупый.

Дано: роутер с белым IP адресом (пусть будет 1.1.1.1), сервер с nginx на борту с одним приложением (site1.com)
Вопрос: Если запрос приходит на адрес 1.1.1.1 на 80 порт, как роутер должен понять, что запрос необходимо направить на веб сервер? Предположим, что в настройках файрвола на роутере настроена маршрутизация трафика поступающего на 80 порт и все запросы идут на веб сервер в локальной сети. Но что если в локальной сети имеется два веб сервера (для балансировки нагрузки)? В таком случае все запросы будут поступать на один сервер, а второй будет просто стоять. В таком случае придётся делать балансировку на роутере? Объясните пожалуйста, кажется я в корне не правильно понимаю как должна быть выстроена инфраструктура.

Comment: Да, балансировка должна быть на роутере или отдельном балансировщике на которй приходит изначальный запрос

Comment: Насколько я знаю, в таком случае обычно ставят ещё один nginx (ну или haproxy), который и раскидывает запрос по разным серверам

Answer (score 0):

Конечно можно балансировку сделать на роутере как написали выше, но это сильно зависит от роутера тяжело тут что то посоветовать.

Но "простую" балансировку можно сделать и на nginx
[https://ruhighload.com/Балансировка+бэкендов+с+помощью+nginx](https://ruhighload.com/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%B1%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2+%D1%81+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E+nginx)

Конечно в очень серьёзных нагрузках требуются совсем другие подходы с дублирующимися ip адресами у прочим весельем, но думаю вам не это нужно